# Universal cover of a not-necessarily-complete hyperbolic manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

The Cartan-Hadamard theorem (as typically stated) tells us that the universal cover of a geodesically complete and connected Riemannian manifold $M$ with non-positive sectional curvature is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If $M$ is a hyperbolic manifold (constant negative sectional curvature) which is incomplete, can we still conclude that the universal cover will be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$? If so, is there a reference for this fact?

For example, we could take a complete hyperbolic manifold and puncture it by removing a point to obtain an incomplete one, or we could cut the complete hyperbolic manifold in two along a separating hypersurface if one exists.

Comment: You answered your own question by puncturing a complete hyperbolic $n$-manifold (if $n>2$).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Could you please elaborate? I'm not seeing how that answers the question.

Comment: Ah I see now; don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb H^n$ and remove one point. If $n> 2$ it is simply connected and thus is the universal cover of itself.

Comment: Oh wow can't believe I didn't think of that.